# image into mail body in iphone

Tags: ios, image, cocoa-touch, email, mfmailcomposer

how to insert uiimage into body of mail composer window.. i have with this code:

```
NSMutableString *emailBody = [[[NSMutableString allocinitWithString:@""] retain];
[emailBody appendString:@" type text here"];
UIImage *emailImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"20-gear2.png"];    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(emailImage)];
NSString *base64String = [imageData base64EncodedString];
[emailBody appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"",base64String]];
NSLog(@"emailBody....%@", emailBody);
[emailBody appendString:@""];

    NSLog(@"emailBody1....%@", emailBody);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposerController =   [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
[mailComposerController  setSubject:@"Your subject"];
[mailComposerController setMessageBody:nil isHTML:YES];
NSData *imageData   =   UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:"your image.png"]);
[mailComposerController addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"image.png"];
```

Hope this help you...

Comment: You call `UIImagePNGRepresentation()` twice there, it's only needed once though. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(yourImage);
[mailController addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:imageName];
```